# Trying to create a trigger that updates a table when a value in another table is changed (oracle apex)

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-apex

So I have two tables, one is called "device" the other is "devicerequest"

The "device" table has columns including id (primary key), name, quantity and basically has data like "(1, iPhone, 3), (2, iPad, 1), which is saying: id=1 name=iPhone quantity=3.

The "devicerequest" table has columns including requestid(primary key), deviceid, devicequantity, and has data like (22, 1, 2) which means that it is requesting 2 of the iPhones.

So basically I am trying to create a trigger when the admin confirms the request (their is an approval column in "devicerequest" (which is NULL when a projectrequest is made) and sets it to 'Y' which means yes to the request, it should change the quantity column in device by subtracting the number that was requested (their is a constraint in place to make sure you do not request devicequantity > quantity).

So I have tried a ton of different variants of this, but still keep getting errors, this is what I currently have:

```
create or replace trigger "DEVICEREQUEST_T1"
before update on "DEVICEREQUEST"
for each row  

begin

if(:NEW.approval = 'Y')
then 
update device set device.quantity = device.quantity - devicerequest.devicequantity
where device.id = devicerequest.deviceid;

end if;
end;
```

I get these errors for this:

6   23  PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "DEVICEREQUEST"."DEVICEID": invalid identifier

5   5   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

I have also tried this:

```
create or replace trigger "DEVICEREQUEST_QUANTITY"
BEFORE
update of "APPROVAL" on "DEVICEREQUEST"
for each row
when (NEW.approval = 'Y')
begin
update device set quantity = quantity - devicequantity where id = deviceid;
end;​
```

I get these errors for this:

2   67  PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "DEVICEID": invalid identifier

2   1   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

I am using Oracle Application Express 4.2.5, thanks for any sort of help I have been working on this for a while and cannot figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UPDATE` statement would be something like

```
update device 
   set device.quantity = device.quantity - :new.devicequantity
 where device.id = :new.deviceid;
```

Of course, in a real system, if admins can be approving requests in parallel, you can easily come up with cases where this would cause the `quantity` to drop below 0.

You say that you have a constraint that prevents the `devicequantity` from exceeding the `quantity` but you can't have a constraint that compares data across tables.  You could have a trigger that performs that validation.  If so, it is highly likely that your trigger is not sufficient in a multiuser environment to enforce the constraint you expect it to be enforcing.

Comment: First, thank you so much I was trying this for so long I really appreciate it. Second, this is how my constraint works:   CONSTRAINT "QUANTITYCHECK" CHECK ( "QUANTITY" >-1) ENABLE

Comment: So it will not allow the admin to approve a request if this occurs, however I will need to implement a constraint somehow for the user so they don't request more devices than available...any suggestions?

Comment: @ilikeicecreamsandwiches - You cannot have a constraint that validates data across two tables.  If you want a constraint, both columns would need to be in the same table.  That wouldn't make sense from a data model standpoint, however.  You could write a trigger to enforce that but that has the same race condition issues that the trigger I posted here does in a multiuser environment.  You could create a fast refreshable materialized view that refreshes on commit that has both the number of devices and the total outstanding requests and then create a constraint on the materialized view.

Answer (score 0):

You could issue an update removing the requested amount at the time of the request rather than approval. If the update would cause the qty to drop below zero, you get an error, otherwise you have "reserved" that number for sale and you don't have to worry about requests coming in very close afterwards. When the request is approved, you have that amount locked in, if disapproved, update the qty to "return" the reserved amount.

You might want to adjust the process depending on the length of time between request and approval and/or if there is some way to determine the probability of approval/disapproval. You could reserve, say, 50% of the requested amount rather than all of it for lower probability requests.